# ReactJS Dropzone how to get base filename (w/o extension)?

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I use reactjs dropzone component for file uploading (https://react-dropzone.js.org/). There is `onDrop` handler with uploading files array, contains file names with extension. How could I get base name (without extension)?

Comment: `arrayOfFiles.map(f => {const x = f.split('.'); x.pop(); return x.join('.')})` something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/jonschlinkert/file-name

Simply do

```
const fileName = require('file-name')

const fileNames = filesArray.map(f => fileName(f))
```

Comment: this is for nodejs (

Answer (score 0):

File object it self has the `name` attribute

https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/blob/gh-pages/browser.js#L58